# Why io module object has no attribute 'RawIOBase' eventhough I am using python 2.6

Tags: python

I was trying to create a class in python with 'RawIOBase' as given below.

```
try:
    import io
except ImportError:
    class Serial(PosixSerial, FileLike):
        pass
else:
    class Serial(PosixSerial, io.RawIOBase):
        pass
```

I was trying to run this using Python 2.6, but it is displaying the error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RawIOBase'

I read that RawIOBase is supported from Python 2.6 onwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you do not have another file named `io.py`. If so, it could mask the `io` module in the standard library. You can check which file is getting loaded as the `io` module by printing `print(io)`. It should return something like `<module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/io.pyc'>`.

If there is such a module or package masking the standard lib module, the solution is to rename the non-standard `io` module or package.

Comment: Thank you very Much. There is one more directory with name 'io' and '__init__.py' file exists in the directory. so when I print using print(io), it is displaying <module 'io' from '/projects/phx/tools/io/__init__.pyc'> instead of <module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/io.pyc'>

Comment: Oh the joys of relative imports :-)