# where can I find io.py (python file) on my linux PC

Tags: python

I was trying to create a class in python with 'RawIOBase' as given below.

```
try:
    import io
except ImportError:
    class Serial(PosixSerial, FileLike):
    pass
else:
    class Serial(PosixSerial, io.RawIOBase):
    pass
```

I was trying to run this using Python 2.6, but it is displaying the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RawIOBase'
```

I found the reason for this error is one more directory with name 'io' exists and 'init.py' file exists in the directory. so when I print using print(io), it is displaying

```
<module 'io' from '/projects/phx/tools/io/__init__.pyc'>.
```

And I found that

```
<module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/io.pyc'>
```

should be the path. But io.py file doesn't exist in /usr/lib/python2.6 path. So even though I exported PYHTONPATH to /usr/lib/python2.6, still when I import io, it is referring the local one instead of standard io module.

Can you please let me know where can I find the io.py file so that this program will be working.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/io.py

Comment: If `io.py` is missing from your `/usr/lib/python2.6` path and only `io.pyc` is present, something is broken.

Comment: You should **not** have to add `/usr/lib/python2.6` manually to your `PYTHONPATH`. Your `/projects/phx/tools` should either *not* be on your path or it should not have a `io` directory as it is masking the built-in module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Neither io.py nor io.pyc files exists in /usr/lib/python2.6 path. site-packages directory exists in /usr/lib/python2.6 and inside site-packages directory, there are bunch of python files existing. But io.py or io.pyc files doesn't exist in that directory.

Comment: Then how did you found that `<module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/io.pyc'>` should be the path? That depends heavily on your local installation. What is `sys.prefix` set to?

Comment: I found the path from the below question on stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572003/why-io-module-object-has-no-attribute-rawiobase-eventhough-i-am-using-python-2

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem here. Move `/projects/phx/tools` **off** your search path or rename the `io` directory there to not mask the built-in module instead.

Comment: Note that Unutbu states that: *It should return __something like__*. It is a diagnostics tool, you don't need to go find it; you need to fix the *other* module that is in the way. And if you have done so you can see things work again when importing `io` results in a path **similar** to what Unutbu posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see what you are using right now:

```
import io
print io.__file__
# /usr/lib/python2.7/io.pyc
```

the `.py` file should be in the same directory

You can use also use `locate` in shell to find all `io.py` versions:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/io.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/io.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/io.pyc
# etc...
```

Keep in mind, that it might depend on how are you executing python, using different python version or - for example - IPython, can yield different results.